Mathematica doesn't simplify when there are decimal numbers
Simplify[2*Tan[x/2]/(1 - Tan[x/2]^2)] returns Tan[x].
Simplify[2*Tan[0.5*x]/(1 - Tan[0.5*x]^2)] returns unchanged expression.
Is it possible to workaround this?

Maybe: Simplify[Rationalize[2*Tan[0.5*x]/(1 - Tan[0.5*x]^2), 0]] ?

IN general, it is better to stick to exact numbers when using a CAS, unless the operation you are doing is numerical in nature (such as NDSolve, NSolve, NIntegrate and so on).  But In this case, I do not see why using 0.5 vs. 1/2 should have made difference, it could be some internal code in Mathematica was not happy with using real numbers and it short circuit. I tried the same thing in Maple, and it produced the expected result there which is tan(1.0*x). Here is screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/mdO2dnKD.png  any way, general advice is to use exact numbers in CAS. Just to be on safe side.

The main gist of the problem is covered by @Nasser's problem. As a trick, sometimes you have to go around a bit, for example: FullSimplify[TrigExpand[2*Tan[0.5*x]/(1 - Tan[0.5*x]^2)]] returns Tan[1. x].
